# Excel not recognizing 0 in a cell in IF statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, zero

I'm getting a #NAME? error when using the following formula:

```
=IF('IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!L2=0,yes,no)
```

The answer should be "yes".

The cell L2 says 0 in it; it's the results of the following formula, where the answer was an error (and I set IFERROR = 0):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('DATA DistS1'!$A$2:$AT$500, SMALL(IF('DATA DistS1'!$A$2:$A$500='DISTRIBUTION NUMBERS'!$A2, ROW('DATA DistS1'!$A$2:$A$500)),ROW($1:$1))-1,46),0)
```

Any ideas? I would really appreciate it! I'm in a tight deadline to get this out before tomorrow morning.

Comment: put quotes around `yes` and `no`

Comment: didn't see your comment. You have the answer. If you post yours, then I will remove mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF('IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!L2=0,"yes","no")
```